# Visual Studio 2015 extension to generate a ToString() method in a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-generation, tostring, visual-studio-extensions

With extension I meant a Visual Studio Extension.

I want to know if there's a way to autogenerate a ToString method with an already created extension.

I want to have a class with some properties and use a tool to generate the ToString method using its properties.

```
class A {
    String propA { get; set; }
    String propB { get; set; }

    // Autogenerated
    override ToString() 
    {
        return "propA = " + propA + ", propB" + propB;
    }
}
```

If not, I want to know how can I make one. I searched the web but I can't find the correct way to add custom code to a already created class with a extension. Especially the project type I need to create.

Edit:
This question [Is there a ToString() generator available in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932136/is-there-a-tostring-generator-available-in-visual-studio-2010) didn't answer what I want; you can't use a snippet to generate code from the properties of the class. You can only add code or replace some created code.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: you can always override the `ToString` method in your class.

Comment: Maybe you could post some code that you have tried or just add more detail.

Comment: class can have more than one extension ... I dont undestand what is a problem....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a ToString() generator available in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932136/is-there-a-tostring-generator-available-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: That question didn't answer mine. Also, snippets can't generate the code I want

Comment: You need to create a vsix project and create your own extension. How to set up this you can search msdn. There you can implement all logic you would like.

Comment: But I don't know what I need to create in the vsix, I couldn't find the information to do what I want (modify an existing class with custom code)

Comment: Sounds like a Code Refactor project to me, which means you're going to need to get into Roslyn. There's samples here that might help: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Samples-and-Walkthroughs

Answer (score 0):

On vs2015 you can build a CodeFix project. see: [Build CodeFix ex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904670.aspx).
On that project you can easely add your logic for adding ToString as part of vs15 new Analyzers.

Option 2:
I'm part of OzCode team and we create a great tool that one of it's features is to create a custom "ToString" method, on the fly (while debugging) I'm adding a linq the the [Reveal](http://o.oz-code.com/features#reveal) feature