# How do I generate a ToString() in Visual Studio that includes all properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tostring

I'm a Java Developer, used to the 'generate toString()' option in Eclipse which offers a complete toString, printing values of all instance variables.  I'm just looking for the comparable shortcut in Visual Studio.

I've seen how you can begin typing the method, "public override " and autocomplete will stub a ToString() but it will not fill it in with all the class properties.

```cs
    public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }
```

I'd like the generated method to include all properties of the class.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506922/visual-studio-2015-extension-to-generate-a-tostring-method-in-a-class

Comment: `ToString()` doesn't usually return *all properties of the class*. It has specific uses, you set it up as necessary. But you could: type the properties :), use Reflection, create a code snippet (see the Code Snippet Manager under Tools) that makes it happen, use third-party extensions that provide this functionality.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? What would that string look like and how would it be used? A *meaningful* format would be to use JSON and serialize using eg Json.NET's `JConvert.SerializeObject`. That doesn't make a good `ToString()` format though.

Comment: `ToString()` is used to display strings in the debugger, eg in watch windows, *when the type has no DebuggerDisplay* attribute. It's far better to add that attribute with the format you want to see instead of overriding `ToString()`

Comment: Check [Tell the debugger what to show using the DebuggerDisplay Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Option 1: Reflection

You could do this by using reflection. But that can cause performance issues if you have to call that method very often in a short time. And it is not that trivial to code with reflection.

- [Dynamic override of ToString() using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299286/dynamic-override-of-tostring-using-reflection)
- [How do I automatically display all properties of a class and their values in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023462/how-do-i-automatically-display-all-properties-of-a-class-and-their-values-in-a-s)

### Option 2: Resharper

The Visual Studio addon Resharper has this feature:
alt + Insert -> Generate -> Formatting members -> select all -> finish

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Formatting_Members.html

### Option 3: Fody/ToString nuget package

Probably the easiest solution, when you only need public properties. It does not work with public fields.

- https://github.com/Fody/ToString

### Option 4: serialize to JSON

For .Net-Framework with the NewtonSoft.Json nuget

- get the NewtonSoft.Json nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json
- serialize the object like this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public override string ToString()
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

for .Net 5 and newer with System.Text.Json

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#how-to-write-net-objects-as-json-serialize

```
using System.Text.Json;

public override string ToString()
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
}
```

Comment: Nice option with Fody. It is a remarkable peace of software. I would still opt for (2)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try Resharper for sure.

Comment: The resharper option is nice, but would be much nicer done as `string.Join(", ", $"{nameof(Prop)}: {Prop}", ...)`

Comment: @xandermonkey i prefer not using string.join. it is more verbose in this case.

Answer (score 13):

You could use JSON.NET to serialize your class.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One more additional way not mentioned in the answer is to use following Visual Studio extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavideLettieri.AutoToString. Once extension is installed, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>**.**</kbd> inside class body, and there will be additional `Generate ToString()` action available.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of what you say about Java and Eclipse.

@RawitasKrungkaew answer is good.

If you don't want to use JSON, you can use reflexion with an extension method to have reusability:

> In some class

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return this.GetPropertiesAsText();
}
```

> PropertiesListerHelper.cs

```
using System.Reflection;

static public class PropertiesListerHelper
{
  static private bool IsProcessing;

  static public string GetPropertiesAsText(this object instance)
  {
    if ( IsProcessing )
      return $"<Reentrancy in {instance.GetType().Name}.ToString()>";
    IsProcessing = true;
    try
    {
      string result = "";
      var list = instance.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(item => item.Name);
      foreach ( var property in list )
      {
        var value = property.GetValue(instance);
        result += $"{property.Name} = {(value == null ? "<null>" : value)}, ";
      }
      return result.TrimEnd(", ".ToArray());
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
      return $"<Exception in {instance.GetType().Name}.ToString(): {ex.Message}>";
    }
    finally
    {
      IsProcessing = false;
    }
  }
}
```

So the behavior works even if the class design is changing.

You can adapt the method to format the output as you want, for example:

```
foreach ( var property in list )
{
  var value = property.GetValue(instance);
  result += $"{property.Name} = {(value == null ? "<null>" : value)}"
          + Environment.NewLine;
}
return result.TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToArray());
```

The management of the case of reentrancy may be improved because it can cause stack overflow on forms for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Visual Studio has an action to perform that kind of code generation out of the box.
You can however do that with the go-to extension of Visual Studio: JetBrains Resharper.

It has an action for quick ToString generation (along with many, many other features).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Formatting_Members.html

Comment: My immediate thought was ReSharper, but I couldn't see a way to do it.  I didn't know that Generate Code menu existed... thanks!

Comment: Resharper is a God send ;). Visual Studio without Resharper may not be the best IDE around, but VS with Resharper beats everything else hands down.

Comment: Yeah, been using it for years now.  Main work is still in VS2017, have been dabbling in 2019 without R#, but I'm nearing the point of installation...

Comment: @JamesThorpe look at the generate comparison members: the generation of getHasCode and Equals is fantastic.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try Resharper.  Sounds awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do it by default - what you're seeing in Eclipse is a nicety of Eclipse, rather than built in functionality of the runtime. You can code an extension to VS yourself (check my comment) or you can use an extension that does it. I know that R[esharper offers the facility](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Formatting_Members.html), but I must stress that SO is not a "find me a library that does..." service so I do not offer any endorsement or recommendation of Re# in any way

It might also be worth pointing out that:

1. You could do this relatively easily in a capable text editor
2. You could write a small app that generates a tostring upon copying a class to the clipboard
3. You could drop your desire for it; in c# we don't really use ToString() anywhere near as extensively as java bods do because we've had a wonderful step debugger built into the IDE ever since it was first released. We seldom need to stringify our objects and dump them to a command line to inspect the state of the program's objects at any point, because we can just pause it and see it in the Locals window etc. If you're not fully up to speed with everything the debugger can do for you I recommend taking a look at a few videos

Answer (score -3):

You can do like this:

```
 public override string ToString()
 {
     return "First name: " + FirstName + ", Last name: " + LastName;
 }
```

or maybe better solution:

```
 public override string ToString()
 {
     return nameof(FirstName) + FirstName + ", " nameof(LastName) + LastName;
 }
```

Use cast on property if it is necessary.